# C# Capturing Direct 3D Screen

Tags: c#, direct3d, gif, screen-capture

I have been fooling around with screen capture for awhile now and I managed to capture the entire screen, certain areas on the screen etc...

But when I go into a game and try to capture the screen, it completely ignores the game and instead, captures the desktop (or whatever is behind the game window).
Another interesting fact is that the same thing happens with the PrtScn button.

Any ideas on how to capture a game's screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The screen capturing technique you are using works well for capturing things that aren't hardware accelerated. I suspect you'd have the same problem trying to capture a movie frame in Windows Media Player.

The solution is the do a screen capture from the hardware itself using DirectX. [This article](http://spazzarama.com/2009/02/07/screencapture-with-direct3d/) explains how to do that with some code and a managed wrapper around DirectX called [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/).

**EDIT**
If Slim DX doesn't work for you, then you'd just have to find another managed wrapper around Direct X. I don't think you are going to be able to do the screen capture without working at the hardware level, and DirectX is the means of doing that on the Windows platform.

Comment: It requires SlimDX which is not very good because you'd have to install it anywhere you go.

Comment: @Or Betsalel You don't have to use the installer. You can also distribute the SlimDX binaries along with your application. The only reason SlimDX has an installer is to install Microsoft's DirectX runtime as well.

Comment: You mean just distribute the Bin Folder? no need for the installion?

Comment: Alright, but this example doesn't seem to work, do you have any other examples or a sample (excutable) with a source? *It works on desktop and other windows but not in games.

Comment: Or Betzalel - No, I'm not an expert on the subject, but a little bit of time spent Googling turned up plenty of results.

Comment: There is also a more up to date example that uses SharpDX: http://spazzarama.com/2011/03/14/c-screen-capture-and-overlays-for-direct3d-9-10-and-11-using-api-hooks/