# Take screenshot: WinForms application with Web Browser Control in Form in Windows Server

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-server-2008

I am using the following code to capture a `Form` screenshot:

```
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.Activate();
            Application.DoEvents();



            Bitmap screenShotBMP = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics screenShotGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenShotBMP);
            screenShotGraphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            screenShotBMP.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Gif);
            screenShotGraphics.Dispose();
            screenShotBMP.Dispose();


            this.TopMost = false;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

When I am logged in to the server, it works fine (I can see the screenshots generated) But when its locked, the line:

```
        screenShotGraphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

> Gives the error "Handle is invalid".

I came to know that its because there is no desktop when no one is logged in. So can anyone let me know any alternatives?

What I have is a WinForms application, scheduled to run after every 5 mins and when it runs, I have to take a screenshot of the `Form`.

Please let me know a soluion.

Comment: Have you tried the [DrawToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) method?

Comment: I tried but the image is blank, although there is one web browser control over it.

Comment: Have you tried the PrintWindow api? I'm curious if it would work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3474843/1429439

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be possible. When a workstation is locked, Winlogon switches to the secure desktop. In this case, like you said, there is no desktop of which to take a picture.

Not even administrators have access rights to the secure desktop, so you couldn't take a picture of *it*, even if you wanted to. The only possible way to work around the security restrictions you're running afoul of here is to rewrite the application as a service so that you would gain access rights to the secure desktop, but then you would run into another set of security restrictions: namely, that services aren't allowed to interact with the user in any way and therefore do not have a "desktop".

It's unclear what you even *expect* to happen in this scenario. If there's no desktop to take a picture of, what would you *want* it to take a picture of?

The bottom line is that Windows is a multi-user operating system and has been for decades now. You have to give up on this 16-bit conceptual model where there is only one "desktop" and everyone has full access privileges to everything.

There are other, better ways of monitoring what is happening on a workstation than taking periodic screenshots… Ways that actually work even. I can't make general suggestions because it depends on what exactly you're trying to monitor.

Comment: I want to take the screenshot of the Form, not the desktop.

Comment: There is no form if there is no desktop. Forms run on a desktop.

Comment: If I convert in into a service, and give it access to secured desktop than, will it be able to take screenshots ?

Comment: "*then you would run into another set of security restrictions: namely, that services aren't allowed to interact with the user in any way and therefore do not have a "desktop".*"

Comment: So the crux is that its impossible, right ? So what should I do ? Basically the application opens website in web browser control and checks if the login is successful or not. If its not, takes the screenshot and mails it. What option do I have ?

Comment: You can parse the content of the `WebBrowser` document and check if the login is successful.

Comment: Right, but I have to send the picture of browser too :(

Comment: @CodyGray: Your comments on above answer by C.M.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the PrintWindow api and it worked with my desktop locked: [C# PrintWindow returns a black image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6827066/1429439)

Comment: I will just try it tomorrow and let you know. If it works, it will be a life saver for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `PrintWindow` function causes a `WM_PRINT` message to be sent to the window. A `WM_PRINT` message instructs the window to draw itself into the specified device context. That's all well and good, except that the WinForms `Control.DrawToBitmap` function is already doing exactly this (sending a `WM_PRINT` message to the underlying control window), and we've [already established](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361760/take-screenshot-winforms-application-with-web-browser-control-in-form-in-window#comment21704020_15361760) that this doesn't work for @Akshay.